# MacVim Add all project files to buffer list

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

I'm using MacVim with The NERD tree plugin and am opening my files by navigating to my project directory in terminal and typing `mvim *`. I'd like to load each of my project files into the buffer list so that I can conveniently navigate between buffers and I've tried `:args *`, but that only created a new file called `*.rb`. How can I add all of my project files to the buffer list?

Answer (score 1):

```
:args **/*.rb
```

will load recursively every ruby file under the current directory in the arglist.

`**` is used for recursive search.

Note that the argument list is not exactly the same as the buffer list. See their respective doc entries.